# How to change alpha of accessory view in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am setting a image for accessory view in UITableView.I am trying to reduce the alpha of this view.This is what I have tried, which doesn't work.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      UIImageView *accessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"]];
      accessoryImageView.alpha = 0.7;
      cell.accessoryView = accessoryImageView;
      return cell;

}
```

Also tried this, with no success :

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      UIImageView *accessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"]];
      accessoryImageView.alpha = 0.7;
      cell.accessoryView = accessoryImageView;
      return cell;

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubClass of UITableViewCell, and try this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.accessoryView.alpha = 0.7f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
   [accessoryImageView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

          UIImageView *accessoryImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"]];
          [accessoryImageView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7]];;
          cell.accessoryView = accessoryImageView;
          return cell;

     }
```

Comment: (Totally as an aside, please note that you should have rejected [this suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4193401). Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your willDisplayCell method

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.accesoryView.alpha = 0.4;
}
```